# Fazer consulta usando Object com o Entity Framework

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-5, entity-framework-6

Tenho um método que recebe um `object` que pode ser tanto `int` como `string`, alguém sabe uma maneira de fazer o `entity framework` interpretar o object!?

Sei que posso fazer um `if` e fazer a verificação, mas estou tentando fazer de uma maneira mais simples pois usarei em vários locais do código.

Segue abaixo exemplo do código:

```
public JsonResult LoadForm(object id)
{
     if ((form = db.tbSystFormulario.FirstOrDefault(f => f.pk_id.CompareTo(id) == 0)) == null)
     {
          form = db.tbSystFormularioCampo.FirstOrDefault(f => f.tx_nome.CompareTo(id) == 0);
     }

     return Json(LoadForm(form), JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
}
```

Comment: Não entendi bem. Se for pra fazer uma consulta pela chave primária, use db.tbSystFormulario.Find(id)..